# "Linux supports the dynamic loading of kernel modules. "

Tags: linux, kernel, unix, history, kernel-modules

I read in a book written by Robert Love that:

> Linux supports the dynamic loading of kernel modules.

He said this is the difference between Linux and Unix, but I seem to recall there is also KLD in FreeBSD? So can KLD also be seen as dynamic loading of kernel modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KLD is indeed dynamic kernel modules. In fact, many old school Unixen also have loadable kernel modules nowadays. Your book must be quite old :)

Answer (score 5):

You're not giving enough context, but I suspect he meant the historical Unix implementation (from the late 60s to early 80s), which indeed didn't have loadable modules. Linux was one of the first unices to get loadable modules, but I think SunOS (then not called Solaris) was there first.

Comment: Upvote if you think Gilles it's omnipresent